# How to view a simple create-react-app component offline?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, create-react-app

Specifically, I have a very simple calculator component. No databases involved, just simple computations done client-side.

I want to use this component on an old laptop that cannot connect to the internet.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: compile it, youll get html and js files, just run the html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React doesnt require internet if database is not used. Just build project, and send index.html to any device you want